# ImageFolder in DCGAN tutorial

Tags: python, root, dcgan

I'm trying to run code for a Deep Convolutional GAN from the official PyTorch site (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) on my Mac.

When I try loading the data, I keep getting the following error that I do NOT understand...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-bec0201fbe1a> in <module>
----> 1 dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root=dataroot,
      2                        transform=transforms.Compose([
      3                            transforms.Resize(image_size),
      4                            transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
      5                            transforms.ToTensor(),

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in __init__(self, root, transform, target_transform, loader, is_valid_file)
    308             is_valid_file: Optional[Callable[[str], bool]] = None,
    309     ):
--> 310         super(ImageFolder, self).__init__(root, loader, IMG_EXTENSIONS if is_valid_file is None else None,
    311                                           transform=transform,
    312                                           target_transform=target_transform,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in __init__(self, root, loader, extensions, transform, target_transform, is_valid_file)
    141             is_valid_file: Optional[Callable[[str], bool]] = None,
    142     ) -> None:
--> 143         super(DatasetFolder, self).__init__(root, transform=transform,
    144                                             target_transform=target_transform)
    145         classes, class_to_idx = self.find_classes(self.root)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/vision.py in __init__(self, root, transforms, transform, target_transform)
     15             target_transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
     16     ) -> None:
---> 17         if isinstance(root, torch._six.string_classes):
     18             root = os.path.expanduser(root)
     19         self.root = root

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '_six'
```